# How to cut a hole in an SVG rectangle

Tags: svg

So basically as my title says, I want to "cut a hole" in a rect element.

I have two rect elements, one on top of the other. The one on the bottom has a fill colour of white, and the one on the top has a fill colour of grey.

What I want to do is cut a triangle out of the top rect element so that the rect element below shows through.

This svg element is going to be used as an audio button for a media player on a page. In other words, you'll be able to click (or drag) your mouse left/right and the change in audio level will be represented by a change in the width of the rect element on the bottom, which shows through the triangle cut out of the top rect element.

I hope that's not too confusing. :P

Here is a quick mockup of what it should look like: http://forboden.com/coding/s1.png

Here is my code: http://forboden.com/coding/svgClipTest.html

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: "Where am I going wrong here?": you didn't put the code in the question and now it's lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `<path>` with the hole, and set pointer-events to `none` so events can pass through to the `<rect>` under. Of course there are many other ways to handle events such as wrapping them with a `<g>` and handling events on it.

You don't need to limit yourself to the basic shapes and use complicated clipping. Make things felxible enough so you can copy&paste path data generated by tools like inkscape.

Comment: Thanks for the path suggestion. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/kju3Q/5/

Answer (score 99):

You should be able to use the [`fill-rule: evenodd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty)(default) property to achieve this effect, if you want to prevent the fill of the rectangle from painting where the circle is. See [this example from the SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/painting/fillrule-evenodd.svg):

[image: A pentagram and two circles, filled in red, with the centers cut showing the white background]

The key point is draw outer shape and inner shapes(holes) in different direction (clockwise vs anti-clockwise).

- Draw the outer shape clockwise and draw the inner(holes) shapes anti-clockwise.
- Or conversely, draw the outer shape(holes) anti-clockwise and draw the inner shapes clockwise.
- Concat the path datas of outer shape and inner shapes(holes).

You can cut more holes by concat more hole path data.

This image explain how to cut a hole:

[image]

Comment: This is on the right track, but doesn't explain how to do it (use a `<path>` with arcto commands).

Comment: use arcto draw outer cirle then inner circle in one path with different directions like this picture.

Comment: The direction of the paths doesn't actually matter. evenodd just makes it so that every time you cross a path, it "toggles" the state between fill and don't fill. The triangle example would work just as well with them both going clockwise or both going anti-clockwise.

Comment: @JakeGriffin fill-rule can be "nonzero" not only "evenodd". path direction take difference under "nonzero" mode.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way how to solve overlapping "holes"? Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446544/svg-using-path-element-to-create-an-area-with-holes).

Comment: amazing illustrations, thanks for this explanation

Comment: is there anyway to draw cicle path? I need to draw rectangle with circle hole on the top of it.

Comment: @YestayMuratov Use `A/a` command to draw circle, like the first example.

Answer (score 14):

I see that you have it solved already, just wanted to add that if you want something more advanced then it's often quite easy to use a `<mask>`, see http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/svg/masking-path-11-b.svg for example.

However, if you can avoid masking and clipping (e.g by just drawing things on top) that usually leads to better performance/user-experience.