# Analytics Project SVG Path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, rotation, geometry

I am not able to figure out how to make path of a circle to go in the middle. I have an example on jsfiddle.

Basically, how do we make this black path go in the middle? This is the path (2nd in svg tag):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

https://jsfiddle.net/6e1z6xkq/

```
<div align="center">
<div class="circleDraw">
<svg width="116" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(58,58)">
    <path d="M-44.430577700900734,37.281681361819274A58,58 0 1,1 44.43057770090073,37.28168136181928L35.23804438347299,29.568230045580812A46,46 0 1,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(100, 150, 100);">
    </path>
    <path d="M-90.430577700900734,97.281681361819274A58,58 0 0,1 -96.07604799105425,3.22779870395063L-96.54307254462923,7.939288627271193A46,46 0 0,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 1, 1);" width="15px" height="20px">
    </path>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer, I believe this is what you are asking for.

Comment: @JoeB. No sorry you were right before. I want to make this path go in the middle (<path d="M-90.430577700900734,97.281681361819274A58,58 0 0,1 -96.07604799105425,3.22779870395063L-96.54307254462923,7.939288627271193A46,46 0 0,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 1, 1);" width="15px" height="20px">
              </path>). Not create a circle

Comment: I got the gist. If you could be more descriptive of how it's positioned in the middle I can provide a better example. But my answer should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Oh sorry @JoeB. I have updated the question with end result with the picture as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. See the updated post

Comment: Oh that's great, i love it. Is it possible to make it static or to leave at a certain position? Right now it changes dynamically when you hover over.

Comment: Yeah you set the `stroke-dashoffset` in the css to any number between 285 and 515 (for the example you provided)

Comment: Thanks @JoeB. appreciated.

Comment: Yup! Please mark as answered when you get a chance!

Comment: What if it's already in the half of the circle (starting point), how do we move it forward?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150365/discussion-between-joe-b-and-user2501165).

Answer (score 0):

## Positioning and animating a line within the svg

It was easiest to go into Illustrator to create a stroke path that matched your arc.

From there it is just a matter of animating the svg with the following css. For any point along the path you can set the `stroke-dashoffset` from 285 to 515 (for this example.

```
  .speed{
   stroke-dasharray: 260px;
   stroke-dashoffset: 285;
  }
```

## To Animate The stroke with CSS

You can apply a transition of the `stroke-dataoffset` to the complete path ([css-tricks has a good article on this](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)), like so:

```
 svg:hover .speed{
    stroke-dashoffset: 515;
    transition: 1s ease;
 }
```

#### Positioning a circle in the middle of your svg

I apologize I misread the question initially. You will want to add a `<circle></circle>` svg tag with `cx`, `cy`, and `r` attributes. cx and cy are the positioning attributes and r is the radius. In this case cx and cy are set to zero and I've arbitrarily set the radius.

You can read more about basic svg shapes at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes)

#### Moving the red path to the middle

You can add `transform: translate(x,y)` to the appropriate path. 'x' and 'y' represent the x and y coordinates of the path. You can also add other attributes like `rotate()` and `skew()`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) has good explanations of this as well.

Also I noticed in your fiddle that you hadn't closed the `<g>` tag.

```css
.speed {
  stroke-dasharray: 260px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 285;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

svg:hover .speed {
  stroke-dashoffset: 515;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  Hover over the first svg!
  <div class="circleClass">
    <svg width="116" height="100">
      <g transform="translate(58,58)">
        <path  d="M-44.430577700900734, 37.281681361819274A58, 58 0 1,1 44.43057770090073,37.28168136181928L35.23804438347299,29.568230045580812A46,46 0 1,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(100, 150, 100);"/>

        <path class="speed" d="M40.1,33.5l3.4-4.9c12.6-19,11.4-44.3-3.6-62.1C29.9-45.3,15.4-52,0-52c-12.2,0-24.1,4.3-33.4,12.2
                               c-20.4,17.1-24.4,46.8-10,68.5c0,0,2.3,4,3.3,5.1" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="12"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>

<div align="center">
  <div class="circleClass">
    <svg width="116" height="100">
      <g transform="translate(58,58)">
        <path d="M-44.430577700900734,37.281681361819274A58,58 0 1,1 44.43057770090073,37.28168136181928L35.23804438347299,29.568230045580812A46,46 0 1,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(100, 150, 100);">
        </path>
        <polygon points="2,2.50 0,-2.5 -40,30" style="fill:red;" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div align="center">

  <svg width="116" height="100">
    <g transform="translate(58,58)">
      <path d="M-44.430577700900734,37.281681361819274A58,58 0 1,1 44.43057770090073,37.28168136181928L35.23804438347299,29.568230045580812A46,46 0 1,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" style="fill: rgb(100, 150, 100);">
      </path>
      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="25"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: How do we make this red path go in the middle?

Comment: You can apply `transform: translate(x,y)` to the `<path>` tag. I updated the snippet. I'm not sure how you want the exact positioning. It is in the "middle." But I imagine you're looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the below (although I would observe that your SVG source is verbose. You can get the same result from a single move and arc drawing command with a green stroke & appropriate stroke width. And there should be no need for a transform - this looks like a drawing tool export.)

```html
          <div align="center">
            <div class="speedometer--points">
              <svg width="116px" height="100px">
                <g transform="translate(58,58)">
                  <path d="M-44.430577700900734,37.281681361819274A58,58 0 1,1 44.43057770090073,37.28168136181928 L35.23804438347299,29.568230045580812 A46,46 0 1,0 -35.238044383472996,29.568230045580805Z" fill="green">
                  </path>
              <path d="M -45 35 l 45 -45" stroke="red" stroke-width="5">
              </path>
              </g>
              </svg>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is complicated a little due to the fact that your green arc is not a simple little path arc that goes from left to right (or vice versa). It is actually a closed shape that defines the outside of the green shape. So it goes from left to right around the outer radius, then a little straight bit to the inner radius, and another arc back to the start.

It is possible to fill a green shape like that, in a meter like way, using a mask or a clipping path. However it is much simpler to just convert your green meter shape to a simple path that goes from left to right in one direction, and has a thick width.

If we do that, your SVG becomes, something like:

```html
<div align="center">
<div class="circleDraw">
<svg width="116" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(58,58)">
    <! the green path converted to a simple one directional stroke -->
    <path d="M -39.8,33.4 A 52,52, 0, 1, 1, 39.8, 33.4"
          style="fill: none; stroke-width: 12; stroke: rgb(100, 150, 100);">
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Now that we've done that, we can use a really easy method to produce your black meter line.

What we do is make an exact duplicate of the green line (except black this time of course).  Then we apply a dash array to the line that makes it on for 50% of the length and off for 50% of the length.

The length of our arc is 236 units. So we set the dash array to:

```
stroke-dasharray: 118 118
```

```html
<div align="center">
<div class="circleDraw">
<svg width="116" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(58,58)" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 12;">
    <! the green path -->
    <path d="M -39.8,33.4 A 52,52, 0, 1, 1, 39.8, 33.4"
          style="stroke: rgb(100, 150, 100);">
    </path>
    <!-- the black path -->
    <path d="M -39.8,33.4 A 52,52, 0, 1, 1, 39.8, 33.4"
          style="stroke: black; stroke-dasharray: 118 118;">
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

If you need to change the meter to read something other than 50%, then you need to adjust the value of the `stroke-dasharray`.  Just make sure the two values add up to (at least) 236.

[This other question shows how to update the meter with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254656/drawing-circular-path-with-svg-and-controlling-its-start-end/45262541#45262541) if that's what you ultimately want to do.