# CSS ring with background and percentage border width

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm seeking for some advice on creating a "ring" shape in CSS. Here's some important detailed goals I need to achieve:

1. the ring border thickness must be a percentage number, not rm or absolute pixel number, so that the ring shape can be fully responsive based on container size;
2. The ring border need to have a background, for my scenario, the background could be sometimes a combination of 3-4 solid colors, or a gradient color;
3. The filling of the ring must be transparent so user can see the background through it.

Here's a quick example: [image]

Here are a few attempts I used:

1. Make a `border-radius: 50%` div with only border width but soon I noticed the border width cannot be a percentage number;
2. SVG clipping a round div to a ring shape. so far I was not able to successfully make it working... If this is the right approach, please share some snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193675/draw-a-hollow-circle-in-svg

Comment: @kukkuz he asked about css..

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this considering [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) where the idea is to use a `radial-gradient` to create the hole and use fixed value which will make the visible part (the thickness) to be responsive.

```css
.box {
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(red,purple,orange);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(transparent 89px,#000 90px);
          mask: radial-gradient(transparent 89px,#000 90px);

}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}

.container {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:200px;
  animation:change 3s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes change{
  to {
    max-width:400px;
  }
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,pink);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Making responsive rings in CSS is tough. The best I've found is to simply create two circles stacked on top of each other where the top circle's background is the same as the container background. You could do this with 2x elements like in my example or with a pseudo-class.

Pros:

- You get lots of control
- Easily add other content (like pie charts) since the content is "masked"

Cons:

- Background needs to be a flat color and nothing will show through the ring

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #9273B0;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If you MUST see the background through the ring, I'd look into a SVG clip path but that gets really complicated pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

In order to maintain percentage values you can try using a radiel-gradient. However the borders tend to get a little choppy looking.

```
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at     center, 
    rgba(255,113,12,0) 60%,
    rgba(255,113,12,1) 51.5%);
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/SROwl/pen/BMEJzj

Comment: This is actually quite brilliant. Using this technique you can actually simulate anti-aliasing to smooth out that edge: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbqbbX

Comment: Thank you @jerrylow, nice addition! I noticed after posting that aliasing really wasn't too bad on a higher quality screens. The screen I used for testing is not the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vw` or `vh` as a metric. The `border-width` will be calculated based on the viewport width or height depending what you choose. You'll have to do some calculation of what value you want to use:

```
.ring {
  border: 10vw solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErJbxN?editors=1100

With JS: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPbYvm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the `vw` `vh` approach doesn't meet my specific requirement, thinking about the shape is just to fill in the parent div, and the parent div may have different sizes (big or small) on the same view port.

Comment: @AllanJiang I see - is JS/jQuery an option for you then?

Comment: position: absolute; is not required

Answer (score 0):

It is very, very simple.
Just add  `position: absolute;` if you need that :)

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}

.ring {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="ring" />
```