# SVG: using path element to create an area with "holes"

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use SVG path element to define an area with "holes". I would like to use these areas for highlighting of some words of text in an image.

[image: image with text]

[image: image with text and word highlighting]

My goal is to present results from text extraction from an image using the OCR ([Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)). Results will be displayed in my Angular application in form of table with words from extracted text with ability to highlight/show selected word in an image from the user.

Using the OCR I got bounding box for each word of extracted text.

This is how I solved highlighting:

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <image xlink:href="http://www.downloadclipart.net/thumb/17283-ok-icon-vector-thumb.png" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300"/>
  <path fill="#ddd" opacity="0.7" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0 H300 V300 H0 Z M10 10 H100 V100 H10 Z" style="visibility:visible"/>
  <path fill="#ddd" opacity="0.7" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0 H300 V300 H0 Z M150 150 H200 V200 H150 Z" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</svg>
```

Everything works fine. I have problem only with overlapping bounding boxes. I have an utility that converts image width and height and bounding boxes to the "d" attribute of path element.

```
public static String example(int width, int height, List<Box> boxes) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("M0 0")
            .append(" H").append(width)
            .append(" V").append(height)
            .append(" H0 Z");

    boxes.forEach((box) -> {
        sb.append(" M").append(box.getLeft())
                .append(" ").append(box.getTop())
                .append(" H").append(box.getRight())
                .append(" V").append(box.getBottom())
                .append(" H").append(box.getLeft())
                .append(" Z");
    });

    return sb.toString();
}
```

But if boxes overlap, I got result like this

```
<svg height="200" width="200">
  <path fill="red" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0 H200 V200 H0 Z M40 40 H100 V100 H40 Z M10 10 H50 V50 H10 Z" />
</svg>
```

[image: current result]

and I want this

[image: iresult i want]

My question is if there is a better way how to define SVG path element to get result I want.

Comment: You could create a mask with multiple paths and apply the mask to a rect. No fill-rule (or clip-rule) required then.

Comment: Kind of, I'd probably draw a background rect in the mask and then draw the holes as a single path on top pretty similar to what you already have.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/milanhlinak/05vt7oya/)? It is a bit complicated if I want to display multiple holes. Solution with path elements is easy, but I want to solve problem with overlapping.

Comment: I'll finish it off as an answer since you got part way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a mask like this...

The path forms the hole.

```html
<svg height="200" width="200">
  <image xlink:href="http://www.downloadclipart.net/thumb/17283-ok-icon-vector-thumb.png" height="200" width="200"/>
  <path fill="black" opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0 H200 V200 H0 Z M50 50 H100 V100 H50 Z M80 80 H150 V150 H80 Z" />
</svg>

<br>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="Mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="200" height="200" fill="white" opacity="0.5"/>
      <path d="M50 50 H100 V100 H50 Z M80 80 H150 V150 H80 Z" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://www.downloadclipart.net/thumb/17283-ok-icon-vector-thumb.png" height="200" width="200"/>
  <rect width="200" height="200" mask="url(#Mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. You saved my day! Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/milanhlinak/urxv0L4L/) is my final result for others.

Comment: It seems that rect with fill="white" and opacity="0.5" does not work on Mozilla Firefox. fill="#808080" without opacity solved my problem on all browsers.

Comment: @MilanHlinák I think masks are currently somewhat broken on Windows. I'm not aware of anything specific to opacity.